# Why my SKView doesn't cover the whole screen properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm using Sprite Kit and I have a UIView called _gameView in my Storyboard and an i-Ad banner beneath it with few constraints applied to them by using Autolayout and I have subviewed a SKView in it. The strange thing is that not only it doesn't obey the constraints, but also the UIView doesn't cover the full screen and also the i-ad banner overlays the UIView, Why is that? (IntroScene is inherited from SKScene of course.)

```
IntroScene*introScn= [[IntroScene alloc]initWithSize:_gameView.bounds.size];

//Also Tried --> IntroScene*introScn = [IntroScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

SKView *skView = (SKView *)_gameView;    


[skView presentScene:introScn];
```

Update: Ok i figured the _gameView Outlet wasn't inheriting from SKView Class but UIView class so after changing that to SKView in storyboard, Now it shows fully in the _gameView but the problem is that the _gameView doesn't accept any constraints from Autolayout in storyboard, why? Any suggestions?

Comment: samo, samo, samo...  Run a search.

Comment: I did already, I couldn't really figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't accept constraints?  Are you adding the constraints by code or through UI Builder

Comment: i Used autolayout on storyboard and applied constraints on the view i wanted my skview to be presented in, the problem was that no matter what you do, in xcode 7 with ios9 sdk, using sprite kit, the storyboard file wont appear in full screen until you do this trick: simply put Main.Storyboard in the Lunchscreen textfield in app's target/general. It finally showed the Main.Storyboard in full screen.